# How can I sync audio and video from a different source?

Tags: sample-rate, fps

I'm trying to sync my sound coming out from my [Allen & Heath - Qu24](http://www.allen-heath.com/ahproducts/qu-24/) to the video on my camera...can someone help?

Also I'm not too familiar with fps and sample rate.

Comment: If you're going to be making videos and separate audio recordings, you better start getting familiar with [frame rates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_rate) and [sample rates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_(signal_processing)#Sampling_rate).

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't use a clapper when you filmed, then you need to find something in the filmed portion where you can see something happen that causes a percussive sound that was recorded. A drummer hitting a drum that is caught on video and audio is one example.

Then it depends on your software and exactly how you filmed and recorded. If the video and audio run at the same rate in the software, you just have to line one up to the other based on the event you found as discussed in the paragraph above. If they are not running at the same rate in the software (for example, you line it up and then it slowly gets out of time), then you have some more complicated work ahead of you.

You have to figure out exactly what format your camera recorded the video in, and also exactly what format the audio was recorded in, and configure the audio/video editor to be aware of both of those formats and play them back at a compatible rate. Probably the most important thing for the video will be the frame rate, which is probably 29.97 FPS or 23.976 FPS if the audio and video keep getting out of sync. The audio is more likely 48 kHz or 44.1 kHz or maybe 96 kHz (rare, but possible is 88.2 kHz). Once you set the editing software to be aware of the exact framerate of the video and sample rate of the audio, it should make it possible to line them up with each other.